# How to integrate newtinymce + elfinder extension in Yii?

Tags: tinymce, yii-extensions, elfinder

I wanted to integrate `elFinder` with TinyMCE. More specifically, make it available as a *button* somewhere on TinyMCE (like inside `insert picture` dialog).

What I have done so far:
1. have [newtinymce](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/newtinymce/), [elfinder](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/elfinder/) extensions under `protected/extensions` folder. (The author said integrating these two would be cleaner in code)
2. have `ElfinderController`, `TinyMceController` as described on extension page.
3. inside `protected/config/main.php` `component` secion:

```
    'widgetFactory'=>array(
        'widgets'=>array(
            'TinyMce'=>array(
                'language'=>'en',
                'settings'=>array(
                    'language' => 'en',
                    'theme' => "advanced",
                    'skin' => 'o2k7',
                    'plugins' => "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

                    // Theme options
                    'theme_advanced_buttons1' => "removeformat,pagebreak,visualchars,visualaid,|,insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,styleprops,attribs,|,undo,redo,search,replace,cleanup,print,preview,save,newdocument",
                    'theme_advanced_buttons2' => "pastetext,pasteword,|,hr,blockquote,|,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,ltr,rtl,formatselect",//copy,cut,paste,
                    'theme_advanced_buttons3' => "nonbreaking,sub,sup,charmap,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,forecolor,backcolor,fontsizeselect,fontselect",
                    'theme_advanced_buttons4' => "tablecontrols,|,link,unlink,anchor,|,image,media",

                    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' => "top",
                    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align' => "right",
                    'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => "bottom",
                    'theme_advanced_resizing' => true,
                    'relative_urls' => false,
                    'spellchecker_languages' => null,

                    'fileManager'=>array(
                        'class' => 'ext.elFinder.TinyMceElFinder',
                        'connectorRoute'=>'elfinder/connector',

                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    ),
```

4. in view file:

```
    <?php
    $this->widget('ext.tinymce.TinyMce', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'content',
    'compressorRoute' => 'tinyMce/compressor',
        'htmlOptions' => array(
        'rows' => 6,
        'cols' => 60,
    ),
    )); ?>
```

This gives me the TinyMCE editor without `elFinder` window as a button on TinyMCE somewhere (like inside `insert picture` dialog).

When I add the following inside view file, it gives me an `elFinder` **area** directly where I put the code.

```
    <?php $this->widget('ext.elFinder.ServerFileInput', array(
      'model' => $model,
      'attribute' => 'content',
      'connectorRoute' => 'elfinder/connector',
      )
    );?>
```

I guess this means `elFinder` is working. But I don't want it as a separate widget for a field, rather I want it to be **part of** `TinyMCE` as stated at the top.

What else do I need to integrate them?

Answer (score 0):

It was a onfiguration problem. `fileManager` property was not a child of `settings`, but a sibling.
So `config/main.php` part should be something like:

```
'widgetFactory'=>array(
    'widgets'=>array(
        'TinyMce'=>array(
            'language'=>'en',
            'settings'=>array(...),
            'fileManager'=>array(
                'class' => 'ext.elFinder.TinyMceElFinder',
                'connectorRoute'=>'elfinder/connector',
            ),
```